# Eclipse Oxygen - Scanning for Liberty Maven project changes, multiple executions

Tags: eclipse

i use eclipse oxygen, when i start the application the projects where build but then the process "Scanning for Liberty Maven project changes. (Waiting)" will start multiple at once.

[image: Eclipse Oxygen screenshot]

I've tried to start my eclipse with -clean command but this will not help.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue but with eclipse neon. Found the issue was due to WebSphere Liberty WDT plugin version 17.0.0.2. I reverted back to 16.0.0.4 and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Preferences-> Liberty Server -> Prompt before adding